# How do I test a concourse custom resource type?

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

So I have build my own custom resourse type. As, suggested in  [this link](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/developing-a-custom-concourse-resource).

I want to know how to test this docker image? How would I get the docker running?

What would be the command? Would I have to pass additional build parameters?

Is there a particular way custom resource types are tested?

Please provide me all the information.

(thanks in advance)

Answer (score 2):

Most concourse resources get tested [like this](https://github.com/aequitas/concourse-http-api-resource/blob/master/test/test_invocation.py#L57)- you write some test that run the binary, with json piped in over stdin, and then you check the return code and the output.

You can run those tests standalone, or run them [as a part of the build process](https://github.com/aequitas/concourse-http-api-resource/blob/master/Dockerfile#L11)- so just `docker build .` to re-test.